# Animate uicollectionview cells on selection

Tags: ios, ios6, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have created a customlayout and set my cells position attribute in `layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath` like this

```
attributes.center = CGPointMake((size.width/2 - 100) + 100, (size.height/2 - 150) +100);
```

I would like to animate a cell when it is selected. replicating the kind of animations we get with the `initialLayoutAttributesForAppearingItemAtIndexPath` & `finalLayoutAttributesForDisappearingItemAtIndexPath`.

I'd like to do this when a cell is selected and de-selected.

so for instance:

Cell A is in position  `0,0`.  Cell B is in position  `50,100`.  If I select cell B I'd like to animate it to `0,0`.  and at the same time animate cell A to `50,100`.  basically switching positions,  but animated.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a different approach. Just override isSelected in the collectionViewCell.

```
 override var isHighlighted: Bool {
    didSet {
        if isHighlighted {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
                // animate highlight
            }, completion: nil)
        } else {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
                // animate unHighligh
            }, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

In this post [UICollectionView: Animate cell size change on selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13780153/uicollectionview-animate-cell-size-change-on-selection/46052728#46052728) you can see an example on how to animate a size change.

Answer (score 0):

I'm animating the attributes by using didSelectItemAtIndexPath in my UICollectionViewDelegate:

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [_collectionView.collectionViewLayout invalidateLayout];
    UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *newAttributes = [_collectionView layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    //use new attributes for animation
}
```