# Make a CollectionViewCell bounce on highlight in Swift

Tags: swift, view, collections, jquery-animate, cell

For the past couple of hours I have tried to accomplish the following:

In a UICollectionview when I highlight (touch down) a cell I want it to bounce inward a few pixels (to a smaller size) and on release bounce back    to the original size.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,
didHighlightItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {


    collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath)
    UIView.transitionWithView(cell!, duration: 1, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseIn, animations: {

        let center = cell?.center
        let frame2 = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50)
        cell?.frame = frame2
        cell?.center = center!

        }, completion: nil)
}
```

(I have found much of this code example from this question:
[UICollectionView: Animate cell size change on selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13780153/uicollectionview-animate-cell-size-change-on-selection) but this is applied on cell selection. Not highlight.
)

So in the didHighlightItemAtIndexPath I set the highlighted cell to a new size. The size is set correct but the following problems arise:
1: it does not animate, 
2: it moves to position (0,0) and animate back to center position. It should not move position at all - just the size.

I have seen this effect in the Shazam app for reference. It can be seen when you shazam a song (or view a previously shazamed song) on the buttons below the song name.

Answer (score 8):

In the `UICollectionViewCell` subclass you can use the code below. I would recommend not using `touchesBegan` and `touchesEnded`, because overriding these will disable the `didSelectItemAt` delegate method for the `UICollectionView` so you will have to take care of that separately through your own delegation. If you are using `didSelectItemAt` delegate method in your view controller then the correct way to animate is overriding the `isHighlighted` property.

**Swift 3/4-**

```
override var isHighlighted: Bool{
        didSet{
            if isHighlighted{
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.8, initialSpringVelocity: 1.0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
                    self.transform = self.transform.scaledBy(x: 0.75, y: 0.75)
                }, completion: nil)
            }else{
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.4, initialSpringVelocity: 1.0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
                    self.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity.scaledBy(x: 1.0, y: 1.0)
                }, completion: nil)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: After doing this, I am unable to select cells when tapping near edges. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 4** little bit refactored code

```
    override var isHighlighted: Bool {
        didSet { bounce(isHighlighted) }
    }

    func bounce(_ bounce: Bool) {
        UIView.animate(
            withDuration: 0.8,
            delay: 0,
            usingSpringWithDamping: 0.4,
            initialSpringVelocity: 0.8,
            options: [.allowUserInteraction, .beginFromCurrentState],
            animations: { self.transform = bounce ? CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.9, y: 0.9) : .identity },
            completion: nil)

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the general gist, although it doesn't handle all edge cases.

```
class MyCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell
{
    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?)
    {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5) { () -> Void in
            let shrinkTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 0.5, 0.5)
            self.transform = shrinkTransform
        }
    }
    override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?)
    {
        super.touchesEnded(touches, withEvent: event)
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5) { () -> Void in
            self.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
        }
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource 
{
    let l = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    var c: UICollectionView! = nil
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        l.itemSize = CGSize(width: 400, height: 44)
        c = UICollectionView(frame: CGRectZero, collectionViewLayout: l)
        c.delegate = self
        c.dataSource = self
        c.registerClass(MyCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cellID")
        view.addSubview(c)
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        c.frame = view.bounds
    }
    func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int
    {
        return 1
    }
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return 100
    }
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
    {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cellID", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell
        if cell.contentView.subviews.count == 0
        {
            let label = UILabel(frame: CGRectZero)
            label.text = "Row: \(indexPath.row)"
            cell.contentView.addSubview(label)
            label.frame = cell.contentView.bounds
            cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        }
        return cell
    }
}
```

Here's a video: http://cl.ly/1Z3n2S2j0K3t

Sorry for the crappy formatting, Mom called and dinner's ready.

Comment: What a great answer! Just watched the video and it is precisely what I am after! I will try to implement it and accept the answer if I can get it to work :) Thanks for a great answer - hope dinner was good!